# Epsilon delta continuity proof for a basic function

Tags: continuity, epsilon-delta

Take the function $f(x) = e^{x}$ and I want to prove this is continuous at $x=0$ using epsilon-delta definition.

ie. $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists\delta>0 \text{ s.t. } |x - 0| < \delta \implies |e^{x}-1| < \epsilon$

So $|e^{x}-1| < |e^{x}| + |1| = e^{x}+1$

Now $|x - 0| < \delta$ or $|x|<\delta$ so $x<\delta$

Hence $e^{x}+1 < e^{\delta}+1$

Take $\epsilon = e^{\delta}+1$ hence $\delta = \ln{(\epsilon -1)}$. But this doesn't show it because if we choose an $\epsilon \le 2$ we can't find a $\delta > 0$ such that the implication holds.

Comment: Right: Although $|e^x - 1| \le e^x + 1$ is completely true, it's not useful here. This really depends on how you've defined $e^x$, since the proof it's continuous uses different methods depending on the definition.

Comment: Using the inequality $|e^x-1|<e^x+1$ is a bad way to try to prove, cause this is always bigger then $1$, and you need something arbitrarily small.

Comment: So how would I tackle this then? (using epsilon delta not comparison)

Comment: @user2850514 As T. said, you need to tells us what's your definition of $e^x$ (there are several ways to define it). From this definition, the trick is to relate $|e^x-1|$ with $|x|$ (you didn't do this).

Comment: $e^{x}$ is the exponential function, I thought that was well known sorry!

Comment: @user2850514 Reread my comment, I said there are several ways to define $e^x$. It's not that $e^x$ has several meanings, it's that there are several ways to define the same thing.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? $e^{0}=1$, $e^{1} = 2.718...$, I'm talking about that $e^{x}$, I didn't know there was another one.

Comment: @user2850514 Ask yourself why is $e^0$ equal to $1$ and why is $e^1$ equal to what it is. Two common ways to define $e^x$ are:
$$e^x:=\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty\left(\dfrac {x^n}{n!}\right),$$ $$e^x:=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\dfrac x n\right)^n.$$ No one can be expected to solve this problem without a precise definition.

Comment: Well I guess it's equal to both of them since they both give the same result. But I want to use epsilon delta on $e^{x}$ not substituting it for the summation and then doing the polynomial. Also I don't want to do a limit test.. I am doing this for practise so I want to prove it for many different function types, i have already done polynomials

Comment: @user2850514 Yes, it's equal to both of them, but you need to pick one (of these or another possible definition) to solve the problem.

Comment: I want to do it for $e^{x}$.. i.e. if I were to prove $f(x) = x$ was continuous at $x=0$ I wouldn't need to know the definition of $x$..

Comment: @user2850514 But you know the definition of $f(x)=x$, it is $x$. What does $e^x$ mean to you? It's the numbers you get by putting $e^x$ on your calculator?

Comment: I understand this but we don't need to use the series expansion of $\ln{x}$ in order to prove its continuity at some $x>0$ so why would we need to for $e^{x}$..

Comment: @user2850514 You need some sort of definition of $\ln$ to prove its continuity. It doesn't need to be the series expansion, but it needs to be something. Are you following a book? If you are, which one is it?

Comment: For what I understood, he wants some argument that do not relies on some definition for $e$. If that is the case, the problem is the same as to show that $f(x) = a^x$ is continuous at $x=0$, where $a>0$ is arbitrary. 
In this case, there is not of special about $e$, but if the original problem uses the constant $e$, there is no reason to avoid the definitions that Git Gud shown above.

Comment: @Integral That would require a definition of $a^x$, though.

Comment: Continuity of $\ln{x}$ at $x=1$: $|x-1|<\delta \implies |\ln{x}|<\epsilon$ so $|x| < e^{\epsilon}$ then $|x| - 1 < e^{\epsilon} - 1$ now notice $|x| - 1 \ge |x-1|$ for $x\ge 1$ ie. $|x-1|<e^{\epsilon}$. So we can take $\delta = e^{\epsilon}$ which is defined for all $\epsilon$ so $\ln{x}$ is continuous at $x=1$.

Comment: @user2850514 Your proof is wrong for reasons that do not matter. Even if it was right, you are still using $\ln$ properties that can only be justified by a suitable definition of $\ln$. I suggest you ask another question referring to the discussion in these comments. Your confusion will not be resolved here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following 
$$e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \ldots$$

Therefore,

$$|e^x -1| = \left|x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \ldots\right|$$

Taking $|x-0| < \delta$, where $0<\delta<1$ and $\frac{\delta}{1-\delta}<\epsilon$, we have that
$$|e^x -1| = \left|x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \ldots \right| < \delta + \frac{\delta^2}{2!} + \frac{\delta^3}{3!} + \ldots<$$
$$< \delta + \delta^2 + \delta^3 + \ldots = \frac{\delta}{1-\delta} < \epsilon.$$

PS: if you don't know this definition for $e^x$, disregard my answer.

Comment: I want to do it for the function $e^{x}$ without substituting the polynomial. I have already practised polynomials and now I want to try exponentials.

Comment: Cool, but since an infinite sum is actually a limit the strict inequality needs to be justified. This a consequence of $$\left|x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \ldots \right|\leq |x|+\left|\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \ldots \right|<\delta +\delta ^2\ldots$$

Comment: You are right, but looks like my answer is not what he (or she) wants.

Comment: @Integral He doesn't know what he wants. If you read the comments in the question you'll see this. I'm trying to explain.

Comment: Well...that's a problem! Im gonna check, and thanks for the observation.